# exceeding maximum allocated memory

Tags: sd-card, ram

I have a Sony phone which can support up to 32 GB external memory according to Sony specs. but I wanna put in 64 gb memory card. would this be a problem. please somebody reply?!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If it says it can only support 32 GB you can't exceed it.